# Contact Form Not Working with PHP 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a contact form that I altered from an existing template. I uploaded it to a host that just upgraded to PHP 5.6 to test it out, and it works. I just found out that the host which the contact form will be used on is running PHP 5.2. I uploaded the form to to test it with PHP 5.2 and it says that the email has been sent, but nothing gets received.

I am really unfamiliar with PHP, and was wondering what I need to change in order to get it to work on an older version of PHP?

The code is below.

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4>Send us a Message</h4>
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Full Name:*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Company Name:*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Phone Number:*</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Email Address:*</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Project Address:*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your project address.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Project Details:*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="details" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your project details.">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Message:*</label>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                </form>
```

PHP

```html
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['company'])   ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['address'])   ||
   empty($_POST['details'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||

   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }
   
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$company = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['company']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
$details = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['details']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
   
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nCompany Name: $company\n\nProject Address: $address\n\nProject Details: $details\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

JAVA

```html
/*
  Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
   example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
  */
$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // something to have when submit produces an error ?
        // Not decided if I need it yet
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var company = $("input#company").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var address = $("input#address").val();
        var details = $("input#details").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                company: company,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                address: address,
                details: details,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button'   class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("Please send email directly to <a href='mailto:yourmail@domain.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com;>yourmail@domain.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        });
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: There's nothing PHP related that would cause an issue on PHP 5.2, therefore I believe the issue lies in the host's configuration regarding sendmail or whatever they use.

Comment: You might want to have a read at [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail). There are so many things that can cause this behavior, too many unknown for us to say either way.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll read through that link and see what I find.